# List variable is updating between updates

Tags: python

I have the following definition for a function named `intervals`.
From the print statement at the bottom I get this results (which are half-hour time intervals like 9:00, 9:30, etc expressed as lists in lists, I believe).

[[9, 0], [10, 30], [10, 30], [10, 30]]

I would like the following result.

[[9, 0], [ 9, 30], [10,  0], [10, 30]]

The complete log of the run is as follows. Notice that the list `list` is only updated once in the `while` loop between the `print "b(efore)"` and the `print "a(fter)"` statements and yet `list` changes after the `after` and before the next `before`. How can that happen?

```
[9, 30] [[9, 0]] b
[9, 30] [[9, 0], [9, 30]] a
[10, 0] [[9, 0], [10, 0]] b
[10, 0] [[9, 0], [10, 0], [10, 0]] a
[10, 30] [[9, 0], [10, 30], [10, 30]] b
[10, 30] [[9, 0], [10, 30], [10, 30], [10, 30]] a
[[9, 0], [10, 30], [10, 30], [10, 30]]

def intervals(start,end):
    if start>=end:
        return []
    else:
        if 0<=start[1]<30:
            start[1]=0
        else:
            start[1]=30
        list = []
        list.append(start)
        last = start
        new=[0,0]
        while end>last:
            if 30==last[1]:
                new[0]=1+last[0]
                new[1]=0
            else:
                new[0]=last[0]
                new[1]=30
            last=new
            print new,list,"b"
            list.append(new)
            print new,list,"a"
        return list

print intervals([9,0],[10,30])
```

Can anyone fix it?

Comment: Proper-noun, negative-imperative-verb possessive-pronoun plural-noun "noun".  It's confusing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you see this is that on each iteration of the `while` loop you append the list `new` to the end of your list `list` (which you should really rename, since it masks the built-in list type).

Just move the `new=[0,0]` line so that it is the first line in the `while` loop, this will create a new list on each iteration so that your final list won't have several references to the same list:

```
        ...
        while end>last:
            new=[0,0]
            ...
```

Note that if you plan on adding any more complexity to this (for example different intervals than 30 minutes), I would really suggest using the [datetime module](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html), `datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)` would probably be useful, for example:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def intervals(start, end):
    temp = datetime.min + timedelta(hours=start[0], minutes=start[1])
    last = datetime.min + timedelta(hours=end[0], minutes=end[1])
    interval = timedelta(minutes=30)
    result = []
    while temp <= last:
        result.append([temp.hour, temp.minute])
        temp += interval
    return result

>>> intervals([9, 30], [12, 30])
[[9, 30], [10, 0], [10, 30], [11, 0], [11, 30], [12, 0], [12, 30]]
>>> intervals([9, 45], [12, 15])
[[9, 45], [10, 15], [10, 45], [11, 15], [11, 45], [12, 15]]
```

Comment: FJ, yes, that works. Thank you. Can you explain why it works. In the original form, why the "... final list won't have several references to the same list:"? And while I'm asking for more: is there a simple way to add corresponding elements in a pair of lists? [2,3]+[5,10] is [2,3,5,10], but I want the result [7,13]. I am having to add 2+5 and 3+10, which is ok, but inelegant.

Comment: @zerowords You can read up on mutable objects [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html), basically since you are modifying `new`, but not reassigning it, each time you append it to the list you are adding another reference to the same list.  As for adding elements from multiple lists, [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) is useful there.  You could use `[a+b for a, b in zip([2, 3], [5, 10])]` for example, or `map(sum, zip([2, 3], [5, 10]))`.

Answer (score 0):

using `while-else` loop:

```
start_hour=9
start_min=30
lis=[[start_hour,start_min]] #simple initialize
stop_hour=12
stop_min=30

while lis[-1][0]!=stop_hour:
    if lis[-1][1]==30:
        lis.append([lis[-1][0]+1,0])
    else:
        lis.append([lis[-1][0],30])
else:
    if lis[-1][1]!=stop_min:
        lis.append([lis[-1][0],stop_min])


print lis
```

**output:**

```
[[9, 30], [10, 0], [10, 30], [11, 0], [11, 30], [12, 0], [12, 30]]
```

Comment: Yes, this is very informative. It shows how to use double indexing for my list, and also shows how to add to one list element more elegantly. It turns out that I would rather end at [12, 0] instead of [12, 30]. Since I am unfamiliar with while-else loops, could you explain how to do this, or else I can play around? Thanks for you solution. My guess is that all I need to do is drop the else part, actually. Right?

Comment: @zerowords in `while-else` and `for-else` loops the `else` part runs only if the for and while loop have ran successfully without any `break` statement,
which allows them to be used in conditions where we need some flag variables to mark the break of if loop in `if-else` loop.

Comment: @zerowords no don't drop the `else` part just change the value of `stop_min` to `0`

Comment: Ashwini, I don't think changing stop_min to 0 will quite work. Perhaps, I didn't say what I want carefully enough. The start of my original code tried to round "back" start times in the first half hour to 0 minutes, and start times in the second half hour back to 30 minutes. What I changed in these comments is that I don't think I want the end time to be included in the resulting list.